# What is the OS X framework(s) for synthesizing music data?

Tags: macos, cocoa, audio, midi

I'd like to write some code that generates some pretty simple musical tones (notes) and has them output through the speaker (whatever sound device).

I suspect I'll likely need to generate as MIDI data, which I can go figure out independently, but I'm new to audio programming generally and I'm not sure what the best entry point into the system frameworks is. `AudioToolbox` has these `MusicSequence` objects. There's also Core MIDI and Core Audio. None has an obvious interface for "here's a data structure for a bunch of notes, now call this method to play them", so I'll presumably need some combination of these to cobble it together.

I'm confident that OS X supports this. If anyone has context with this kind of work, I'd appreciate a couple basic pointers on where in the docs (or other resources) to start looking for building whatever structures represent music data and where you'd turn around and trigger playback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OS X does support this, but it's a lot more inherently complex than it might seem at first. There are essentially three pieces:

- MusicSequence is the "data structure for a bunch of notes" (along with timing information in the form of a tempo/meter map.
- MusicPlayer is the object that controls playback of the MusicSequence.
- AUGraph is what you'd use to create an instrument object and hook it up to your physical outputs, to turn the note data into sound.

There's a lot of potential variety in how you set up the AUGraph. For example, the default General MIDI synthesizer is the built-in DLSMusicDevice, but you could also load an FM synth, a sampler, or any number of other instrument units. From there, you could be processing the audio in various ways and routing it to various devices. All that stuff that falls in the general category of "audio processing" happens within the AUGraph.

Apple's PlaySequence sample code does mostly what you're looking for. It's a C++ project—but MusicSequence, MusicPlayer, and AUGraph are plain C APIs, so it should be a decent starting point. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/PlaySequence/Introduction/Intro.html